# Question Titles in the Long Run

Tags: discussion

This is a question with a duplicate title to (dis-)prove a point made here:

> "there is no need at all for [the title] to be unique" Except that the Stack Exchange software requires it.
>   – [svick](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1593/question-titles-in-the-long-run/1596?noredirect=1#comment4586_1596)

The title is shared by [How can we avoid redundant titles?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1593/21609)

---

This was made possible by adding extra spaces to the title. They are used for the uniqueness comparison, but get stripped out later.

Comment: Duplicate, but helpful ;)